# how can i solve this error SFML in dev-c++?

Tags: c++, windows, sfml, dev-c++

I try to setup SFML on dev-c++ with this video https://youtu.be/uAd2jINKCxc
but I have an error.
error list:

```
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x183): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf11CircleShapeC1Efy'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x1c8): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Color5GreenE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x1d6): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Shape12setFillColorERKNS_5ColorE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x1fa): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ColorC1Ehhhh'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x287): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget4drawERKNS_8DrawableERKNS_12RenderStatesE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x29a): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x2ad): undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf6Window6isOpenEv'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x2d9): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x307): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text+0x34d): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev]+0x25): undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN2sf11CircleShapeE'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\New folder\main.o  main.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD1Ev]+0x3b): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ShapeD2Ev'
C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\mdi\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
25      C:\Users\mdi0exe\Desktop\mdi\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'mdi.exe' failed
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT5y7.png)

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

how can i solve this error thanks for your helps

Comment: Make absolutely certain you have [the order of the libraries correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: You should move away from Dev C++, it was last updated in 2006. try a video on codeblocks and SFML or better visual studio and SFML. I used SFML on visual studio community 2019 and they worked good. also make sure you follow the steps correctly, if in doubt just delete the project, make a new one and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found out is to copy [.dll's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw5O7.png) to the same repository as yours .exe.
I.e. from ..\SFML-2.5.1-windows-vc15-32-bit\SFML-2.5.1\bin\ to ..\SFML_Tutorial\Debug\